# Trigger a jQuery page redirect after the default form event is completed

Tags: jquery

My page uses a form that downloads a pdf file to a user's computer after the form is submitted.

I want to redirect to a thank-you page after the download took place.

Not being an expert in web stuff, I tried all kinds of things around this type of code:

```
 `click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "mythankyoupage.com";
       
    });
```

But nothing seems to work - either event is not firing (the pdf does not download) or the redirect doesn't happen.

Is there a way to redirect to another page after the download took place?

Comment: Show more of that click code and how it is being called

Answer (score 1):

You can use the assign method:

```
window.location.assign(`mythankyoupage.com`);
```

**Update**

```
document.querySelector(`form`).addEventListener(`submit`, async evt => {

   evt.preventDefault();

   const body = new FormData(evt.target),
       sendReq = await fetch(`yourUrl`, {
         method: `POST`,
         body
       }),
       blobFile = await sendReq.blob(),
       url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobFile),
       a = document.createElement(`a`);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = `fileName.pdf`; // or any other format
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();

    window.location.assign(`mythankyoupage.com`);

});
```

This is a very summed up version of the basics to download a file from your server.

Comment: How should I incorporate that snippet into the form code, please?

Comment: Send the information via fetch, retrieve the blob file, and while it downloads, redirect. I'll update the answer above

Comment: Thank you. Not quite suitable for my purposes. Is there a way to simply execute the default event that the form does, and then execute the script?

Comment: What is the default behavior currently?

Comment: Once the form is submitted, it sends a an instruction to the server to download a file to the user's device.